# Can we write one unique TDE configuration file in marklogic to get data from different entity xml documents

Tags: marklogic-9

Please let me know how to configure TDE to combine data from different entity xml. I mean in sql while creating view we do it by specifying some criteria based on which view will be created, but not individual views and then performing joins.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge that is not supported, and I suspect it won't be supported soon either. TDE is meant as views on individual documents. You will have to use joins at query time for now.

I recommend opening an RFE if you think you have a strong use case for the kind of views you are looking for.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes we do have a requirement to have a unique view fetching data from multiple different documents. Instead of having individual views for each document it's better to have a unique view from multiple documents to generate a report as per the functionality demands.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to raise this RFE?

Comment: Our RFE tracking system is internal only, you'd have to ask an internal person, usually your local MarkLogic contact. It is a known request though, so I added a link back to this question. It's RFE-3537..